# How to return a StatusCode and Data in action method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

How can I return a statuscode and data in a Asp.net web api action method?

I currently just have the status code:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Status(string id)
{              
    var msg2 = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);               
    return msg2;          
}
```

Comment: Did you even bother to google it?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240713/put-content-in-httpresponsemessage-object

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're on the most up to date version, you can just have:

```
public IHttpActionResult Status(string id)
{           
    return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK,myDataFromSomewhere);
}
```

See [`Content`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.content%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

here is an example:

```
string response = "blabla"
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response);
```