# Add Json response in C#.net API for all scenarios

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

How can I return a Json response ALWAYS, it doesn't matter if the HTTP Code needs to be 200, 401, or another one.

For the HTTP 200 the Json is sent with `return Ok(response); //where response is a model.`
For HTTP 401 (Unauthorized) I have the following:

```
throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent(msg),
                    ReasonPhrase = msg
                });
```

But msg needs to be an String... I cannot make it work with a model to return a JSON.

The same happens with BadRequest or other HTTP status.

Answer (score 0):

No one says that  the content of `StringContent` cannot be a serialized object.
Try this:

```
// uses Newtonsoft.Json
var serializedString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObject);
throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
{
    Content = new StringContent(serializedString, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"),
    ReasonPhrase = msg
});
```

Credit goes to [Put content in HttpResponseMessage object?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41076308/634872)