# Return the List items from C# MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list

So I have this code and it should return the list of items but I can't get it to work. I know there is a mismatch between `HttpResponseMessage` and `List<string>` but I am not able to convert it to return.

[image]

I know that it's because of the `HttpResponseMessage` type and list don't match but I don't know how to convert it

```
namespace NovaWebApi.Controllers
{
    public class TermsController : WebApiBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetTermsUrl()
        {
            List<string> terms = new List<string>();
            terms.Add("https://www.nbg.gov.ge/index.php?m=2");
            terms.Add("https://www.fms.gov.ge/");

            return terms;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The message it right there in that picture telling you what is wrong.

Comment: return type should be of HttpResponseMessage type. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240713/put-content-in-httpresponsemessage-object

Comment: If none of these answers provide a solution you can accept as an answer for you please edit your question to indicate why your requirement is not met by them with additional details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HttpGet method returns HttpResponseMessage.Try this one:

```
[HttpGet]

    public List<string> GetTermsUrl()
    {
        List<string> terms = new List<string>();
        terms.Add("https://www.nbg.gov.ge/index.php?m=2");
        terms.Add("https://www.fms.gov.ge/");

        return terms;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, I did that and it worked just fine sorry for the late reply. I haven't tried other ones this one worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to return `List<string>` as `HttpResponseMessage` which is not possible.Try this:

```
public class TermsController : Controller // this part to return Ok() without error.
```

Then:

```
return Ok(terms);
```

Comment: I've tried it but "name Ok doesn't exist in the current contexts"

Comment: Any intellisense suggestions?

Comment: Just to generate a new Ok method

Comment: It did not help sorry. It messed up [httpget] and I changed it to public class TermsController : WebApiBase that we use in different controllers but I still get an error

Comment: Not WebApiBase, you should use Controller to inherit.

Answer (score 1):

Since you indicate you wish to return HttpResponseMessage type, you have to create one that includes your list.

Web API will create a serialized version in the response body using a formatter for the model, in this case your list; writing the serialized model into the response body.

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetTermsUrl()
{
     // Get a list of products from a database.
     List<string> terms = new List<string>();
     terms.Add("https://www.nbg.gov.ge/index.php?m=2");
     terms.Add("https://www.fms.gov.ge/");
     // Write the list to the response body.
     HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, terms);
     return response;
)
```