# Display images using base 64

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, image, base64

I would like to know which is the best way to display images using ajax calls.

I get the data stored in the database as a byte[] array and then I send the data as base64 string to the view using ajax.

With small images this work fine but when there are big size images, I get an internal server error in the response.

And I´m wondering why?

The error message is:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

```
List<string> images = new List<string>();
foreach (var student in students)
{
string base64String = System.Convert.ToBase64String(student.StudentImage, 0, student.StudentImage.Length);     
images.Add(base64String);
}
```

and then the public ActionResult returns this.

```
 return Json(images.ToArray());
```

with small images works fine the problem is with big size images.

Comment: And I'm wondering what the error message is? And how your code might look like?

Comment: Well there is more context, maybe you can look at.

Comment: What's the server-side error that causes the 500 Internal Server Error?

Comment: I solve my problem with something like this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382265/returning-unescaped-json-in-mvc-with-json-net